Movie where the trainee hit man is ordered to kill his mentor
Can't remember which movie is this. It probably has a political angle as well. The mentor has advised his trainee to shoot from a distance to avoid blood getting on his clothes. At the end of the movie the trainee is about to kill his mentor when the mentor reminds the trainee to stand back to avoid blood splatter.
There was one occasion in the movie when one of the hit man went to kill a couple. He dined and wined with them in their house, they all laughed and joked until the hit man finished them spontaneously.
It's an English movie, both actors are white. Saw it either on TV or video. Probably saw it some 10 years ago. It's not an old movie.

Add more information. Year, Language.

which languge was that?

It sounds like it could be Coldblooded
Coldblooded staring Peter Riegert and Jason Priestley

You might want to elaborate in which way this fits to the details from the question in order to flesh out this answer a little more.

Yes it is! When I was searching around, this was the name that came on top but there weren't enough details on imdb. I remembered nothing about bookie and nurse. On your suggestion I watched it again today and yes it is. Thank you very much! This time it didn't appear as shocking as it had appeared when I first saw it. But maybe that was the reason why. The first time I saw it I was blown out of my mind.
